# difference between sencha Free Commericial Version and Open Source Version?

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs

sencha have provided both version for downloading Free Commericial Version  and  Open Source Version?which one is the best? It is a complete freeware?

Answer (score 5):

Sencha Touch (not Touch Charts) has 3 licensing options

- Commercial Software License (Now Free!)
  This is the appropriate option if you are creating proprietary applications and you do not want to distribute and share the source code of your application with your users. You may create unlimited numbers of applications with NO per seat or per user payments.
- Commercial OEM License (Paid license)
  This is the appropriate option if you want to use Sencha Touch to create your own commercially licensed SDK, or mobile application builder. Because use cases can vary widely, Commercial OEM licenses are customized for each customer.
- Open Source License
  Sencha is an avid supporter of open source software. This is the appropriate option if you are creating an open source application with a license compatible with the GNU GPL license v3. Although the GPLv3 has many terms, the most important is that you must provide the source code of your application to your users so they can be free to modify your application for their own needs.

[Details available here](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/license/)

As for Touch Charts, here is what they say when you download the current beta:

> Sencha Touch Charts will be available as an add-on to Sencha Touch
>   under a paid commercial or a GPLv3 licenses. During our beta period,
>   Sencha Touch Charts is free for evaluation under a short-term beta
>   license.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally they're both the same. The difference is in licensing.

**Neither is freeware.**

Open Source version is free, and let's you distribute your applications licensed under GPL or compatible license.

Commercial version <s>is not free</s> is currently free actually!, but let's you distribute your application as closed source.

See here for more details: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/license/